# How to reference a marco variable (date) into a file name

Tags: python

I automated a date variale which is rundate '202002' (YYYYMM) as below and I am trying to export a file to my desktop with file name sales_202002.xlsx. However, file name becomes sales_{rundate}.xlsx instead of sales_202002.xlsx. Could someone please advise? Thanks

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
first = today.replace(day=1)
lastMonth = first - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

rundate=lastMonth.strftime("%Y%m")
rundate
Out[7]: '202002'

sales.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\SaleFolder\sales_{rundate}.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: you either need to use an `f-string` like so: `rf'your string here with variable: {here}'` or you need to use `string.format()` like so: `r'your string here with variable: {here}'.format(here="whatever you would like here"`)`

Answer (score 0):

Change it to a f-string. For more info: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Your last line would be changed to:

```
sales.to_excel(f"C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\SaleFolder\sales_{rundate}.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks you! This works - sales.to_excel(f"C://Users//Sam//Desktop//SaleFolder//sales_{rundate}.xlsx", index=False)

Answer (score 0):

This works - sales.to_excel(f"C://Users//Sam//Desktop//SaleFolder//sales_{rundate}.xlsx", index=False)